# How to make ImageButton clickable in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, methods, imagebutton, clickable

I have done an immense amount of research and for whatever reason whatever I try I cannot get an ImageButton to be clickable in Android studio. I have tried numerous things but I must be missing something. I will past XML file below and then Java below that. When I put setOnClickListener method I get a cannot resolve message and same for when I do onClickListener. I would like the button to link to a webpage. Please help!

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.autismacademyed.www.autismacademy.AutismAcademy">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.173" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonYellow"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_yellowpuzzlepiece"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is Java:

```
package com.autismacademyed.www.autismacademy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class AutismAcademy extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_autism_academy);
    }

    ImageButton imageButtonYellow = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonYellow);
   imageButtonYellow.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener()

    public void onClick (View v) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.aaed.org"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need to set onClickListener, as you already specified onClick attribute in XML, just implement that method in your activity and the syntax for onClickListener is also wrong

Comment: check my answer and let me know what happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `setOnClickListener` since you already specify in your view that the onclick function for the button is `onClick`. To avoid confusion rename your button `android:onClick="onClick"`, like `android:onClick="imageButtonOnClick"`.

And in your java code you can just use this

```
package com.autismacademyed.www.autismacademy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class AutismAcademy extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_autism_academy);
    }

    public void imageButtonOnClick(View v) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.aaed.org"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was that simple! I literally spent hours researching. This is my first app so I am still learning things.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this two file will work for you. You declare two click listener that's why its not working.

**xml file**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.autismacademyed.www.autismacademy.AutismAcademy">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.173" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonYellow"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_yellowpuzzlepiece"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**jAVAFILE**

```
public class AutismAcademy extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_autism_academy);
    }


    public void buttonClick(View v) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.aaed.org"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

}
```